# Is it possible to use 2d terrain (ferr2d) with 3d mesh using mesh collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make simple platformer with ferr2d terrain and 3d mesh as a player. I can set 2d colliders for both to work - but I can't configure ferr2d terrain to work with mesh collider. Is it possible?

I could be doing something wrong, I'm new to unity. If there is any resources/tutorial on the net that can point me to the right direction would be also great.

Comment: If you're just learning, is it really worth using Ferr2D? Just use Unity's superb built-in terrain.  What's your reason for doing so?  And as Martin points out, it's as easy for you to google "Ferr2D" than for someone here to google that for you :)

Comment: I asked this question on ferr2d forum but it's author seldom answers there anymore. Same with unity forums. It's hobby project, I thought ferr2d is good tool for the job - just not sure if what I'm doing (2d colliders) is the best way possible to do it. 

I thought it maight be trivial for someone working with 2.5/3d platformers... maybe it is not, then I would stay with 2d colliders.

Answer (score 1):

> I could be doing something wrong, I'm new to unity. If there is any resources/tutorial on the net that can point me to the right direction would be also great.

- [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)
- [Unity Learning Forums](https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/community-learning-teaching.23/)
- [Unity Official Tutorial Site](https://unity3d.com/learn)
- [Unity Meshes Reference topic](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/meshes)
- [Ferr2d And Unity Tutorial links (google)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=unity+and+ferr2d&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr)
- [Unity Forums Q&A on Ferr2d integration](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ferr2d-terrain-tool.204436/)

There are so many Unity tutorials on the net (admittedly of varying quality) as well as thier own specialist forum as well as a whole Stack Exchange site to this topic, to be honest I would think that the links given above should provide you with enlightenment.